# Check and process expiring assets using chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I created assets with expiry date as one of the attributes.  If the asset is expiring 1 month from now, chaincode must check for certain criteria to determine whether to extend the expiry date or not.  A criteria could be the financial value of the asset.  If value is more than 1M, chaincode will extend the expiry date from 1 month from now to 1 year.  If it is less than 1M, chaincode must notify the client app.

Is it possible to have the chaincode check everyday all assets that are expiring 1 month from now and perform the actions I mentioned above? Or do I need to use some library to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart contracts don't have any kind scheduled job capability built in. They just respond to transaction proposals. You could:

1. Wait until an asset is accessed by a transaction function before making the decision on what its expiry status should be.
2. Have a client application run on a schedule (perhaps as a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job), which invokes a house-keeping transaction function on the smart contract to make changes based on expiry date and value of assets.
3. If querying for assets that may need managing is impractical in a house-keeping transaction function on the smart contract, you could maintain an [off-chain data store](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/off_chain_data)  of assets that can be more easily queried, and have your scheduled house-keeping application use that information to decide which assets need updating by calling appropriate smart contract transaction functions.